# which is the easiest way of managing users and sessions on rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I already developed a big part of my system but I'd like to know if rails 4 provides something interesting and easy to use for this means......Are there any libraries or built-in methods I could use to simplify sessions and users?

Comment: Simplify in what way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking as included in Rails, you may want to explore HttpAuthentication: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html

Otherwise the gems Monban and Devise are pretty popular.

https://github.com/halogenandtoast/monban

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise